# HowTo: specify which schema to point to in a postgresql uri

Tags: postgresql, heroku

So, I'm trying to point to a Heroku PostgreSQL database, which because no schema is specified only points me to public where no data is accessible:

```
postgres://user:password@host:port/database
```

How do I specify which schema to point to on the uri?

Comment: I might be more convenient to change the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) for the database user you use to connect.

Comment: A connection string doesn't point to a schema, but to a database. Addressing a specific schema must be done in the individual queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use `currentSchema`

```
jdbc:postgresql://{host}:5432/{database_name}?currentSchema={scehma_name}
```